# Convex matrix combination

Tags: matrices, convex-geometry, matrix-theory

We all know the notion of a convex combination like

$$\lambda x_1 \; + \; (1 - \lambda)  x_2$$ for some $\lambda \in (0, 1)$.

However, I am trying to find literature where this concept has been generalized to weighting by matrices $\mathbf{W}$ where the singular values act like the lambda, i.e.

$$\mathbf{W} \mathbf{x}_1 \; + \; (I - \mathbf{W}) \mathbf{x}_2,$$

where $\sigma_i \in (0, 1)$ and $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of the square matrix $\mathbf{W}$ and $\mathbf{x}_i$ are vectors. Is there a term for this kind of "convex matrix combination"?

Comment: Are $W$ diagonal matrices? Otherwise $(I-W)$ may have negative values.

Comment: So you add to $x_2$ any vector shorter than  $y=x_1-x_2$,  right?

Comment: @Dieter Kadelka No, $\mathbf{W}$ may be non-diagonal. I do not mind about negative values in the matrix.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ in the second display equation matrices or vectors? (Or scalars?)

Comment: And do the $\sigma_i$ sum to one, or are they arbitrary?

Comment: The $\sigma_i$ do not sum up to 1 in general. I clarified my concern more in the description. Thanks.